# how to load electron module in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ipc, electron

I try to get the ipcRenderer module from electron in typescript to send informations from the current component to the core and to get informations back to the window (electron-chromium-browser).
All I get is a error "Module not found" by transcoding the ts-code to ES5.

const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;`

**Update:** The Error is switching between the "Module not found" and this one:

`ERROR in ./~/electron/index.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT, open '/.../node_modules/electron/index.js'
 @ ./app/components/search/search.ts 12:10-29`

That is from the current [electron-api](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md). I have also tried to use the import syntax from typescript but the result is the same.

Than I tried to use the electron.ipcRenderer module in a ES5-file, loaded/linked directly in the html-file.

There it worked. Why?

Comment: have you tried using the electron-compile module that has support for TS and ES6 and all?

Comment: Another Q/A solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62467092/electron-forge-cant-use-ipcrenderer-in-the-renderer-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solved** the problem after 10h searching.
Problem was the webpack-transcoder.

https://github.com/chentsulin/webpack-target-electron-renderer

https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.development.js

Comment: can you explain a little bit more how you fixed it please? :)

Comment: in my case i use webpack to transcode typescript code to es5, in that way I have a `webpack.config.js`-File. In that config you have to send the hole config through `webpackTargetElectronRenderer(config)` to `config.target`.

it should looks like that:
`var config = {.....}; config.target = webpackTargetElectronRenderer(config);
module.exports = config;`

Answer (score 3):

Since electron dependency in the browser app is not real, meaning it's not webpacked from node_modules but instead loaded in runtime, the require statement caused errors such as "fs" not found for me.

However you can trick the typescript with this:

`if (typeof window['require'] !== "undefined") {
    let electron = window['require']("electron");
    let ipcRenderer = electron.ipcRenderer;
    console.log("ipc renderer", ipcRenderer);
}`

Also if you are writing a web app, which only is augmented by electron when it's running inside, this is a better way since you don't have to add electron as a dependency to your webapp just when using the communication parts.

Comment: Thank you, this is not obvious an under documented. I've been searching for hours for this. I feel there's probably a more elegant solution but this gets me moving again.

Comment: I don't know why this works when `await import('electron')` doesn't, but after spending all day on this I'm not going to question it

Answer (score 1):

> Than I tried to use the electron.ipcRenderer module in a ES5-file, loaded/linked directly in the html-file.

If it works in *html* but fails in *ts* it means the error is not in `const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;`. The error is most likey in the import you have to load *your file* from html (and not `require('electron')`).

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me:

You can fix it, just add to the "package.json"

```
"browser": {
"fs": false,
"path": false,
"os": false }
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8272#issuecomment-392777980

Answer (score 0):

You can trick ts with this (dirty hack, but it works):

`const { ipcRenderer } = (window as any).require("electron");`