# Electron Forge - Can't use ipcRenderer in the renderer file

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-forge

I just created a new application using the following command:

```
npx create-electron-app my-new-app --template=typescript-webpack
```

Inside the **renderer.ts** I added the following code

```
import "./index.css";
import { ipcRenderer } from "electron";
```

But when I run **npm run start** I have the following error in Browser Console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

**Update**
What I've tried:

**webpack.plugins.js**

```
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = [
  new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
  new webpack.ExternalsPlugin("commonjs", ["electron"]),
];
```

But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Found Solution**

The solution is to use ipcRenderer in a preload script.

**preload.ts**

```
import { ipcRenderer } from "electron";
```

**index.ts**

```
declare const MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY: any;

const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  height: 600,
  width: 800,
  webPreferences: {
    preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
  },
});
```

**package.json**

```
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
      {
        "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
        "renderer": {
          "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
          "entryPoints": [
            {
              "html": "./src/index.html",
              "js": "./src/renderer.ts",
              "name": "main_window",
              "preload": {
                "js": "./src/preload.ts"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: George, you may want to add "  declare const MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY: any;" as a note for Typescript users or they'll get an error as the TS compiler will not know about this Global. This can be defined in the main index.ts or you can move these "declare" declarations including the default into "src/typings.d.ts" after creating a declare global {  // your declare const....here }. If you wish I can edit this for you :)

Comment: How do you then reference ipcRenderer in the application? (a React component for example?)

Comment: @BlueWaters to send IPC message from React component, you must enhance the preload.ts script:

    import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from 'electron';

    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('dog', {
      bark(arg1, arg2) {
        ipcRenderer.invoke('dog.bark', arg1, arg2);
      }
    });


Now there is a `window.dog.bark()` function available in your React component.

Comment: I'm close to implementing this solution. I've defined my function in the context bridge and I'm able to call it from the debug console like `window.api.get()`. However, in my react typescript component, I keep getting `window.api is not a function`. How do I declare the new function?

Comment: Hi @EvanLalo! If you use `window.api` I assume you have something like this in your preload script: `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api",{})` correct?

Answer (score 6):

The solution is using the `ContextBridge` API from `electron` for electron-forge [react+webpack](https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/react) template

preload.js

```
import { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } from "electron";

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electron", {
  notificationApi: {
    sendNotification(message) {
      ipcRenderer.send("notify", message);
    },
  },
  batteryApi: {},
  fileApi: {},
});
```

main.js

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
    },
 });

ipcMain.on("notify", (_, message) => {
   new Notification({ title: "Notification", body: message }).show();
});
```

package.json

```
 "plugins": [
    [
      "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
      {
        "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
        "renderer": {
          "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
          "entryPoints": [
            {
              "html": "./src/index.html",
              "js": "./src/renderer.js",
              "name": "main_window",
              "preload": {
                "js": "./src/preload.js"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
```

app.jsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    electron.notificationApi.sendNotification("Finally!");
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>contextBridge</h1>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

Comment: this is exactly what i'm looking for.. thank you so much to answering this bro. appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using typescript, you need to add this to your renderer.ts file:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    electron: {
      funcName: () => void;
    };
  }
}
```

Then you can use `window.electron.funcName()`.

Answer (score -1):

In index.js when creating new window use

```js
win = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'assets', 'js', 'preloader.js'),
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false
        },
    })
```

Simply add `nodeIntegration: true` to webPreferences.Then you would be able to use `require`

Comment: ** nodeIntegration: true** is not recommended because of security reasons

Comment: Not to pile on here but @GeorgianStan is correct, best not to enable nodeIntegration. His above example is the correct answer.