# Electron Forge - Use ipcRenderer in the renderer file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, electron-forge

#### Behavior

I am develop a Electron Forge project. When I'm trying to use `electron.ipcRenderer`, it will cause an error, the app cannot be started. It shows some informations, but it's useless:

```
An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] {
  errno: -4068,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'read'
}

Electron Forge was terminated. Location:
{}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I had created a project with Electron before with Electron forge, is works fine with `ipcRenderer`

Only import in typescript cause the error, require in HTML works fine

#### More Information

`electron.ipcRenderer` and `electron.remote` both cause problem, but import without using will not cause the error.

Window create code:

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 540,
    width: 960,
    resizable: false,
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
    },
  });
```

*The resolution in [Electron Forge - Can't use ipcRenderer in the renderer file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62467092/electron-forge-cant-use-ipcrenderer-in-the-renderer-file) is not work, which is access ipcRenderer in preload.ts*

#### Envrionment

##### Important package versions

```
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.57",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
    "electron": "^13.1.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
```

##### OS

Windows 10 x64, CoreCountrySpecific (aka. 家庭中文版 or Chinese Family Edition), Version 2009, 21H1 (19043.1083), Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0.

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti

#### Possible Reasons

- Webpack can't complies electron, it should be complies directly to `require('electron')`, instead inject electron code into the file

  - If in this case, how to configure webpack to make it doesn't complies electron into a file?
- Electron forge question
- This electron version and electron forge version cannot be used together

  - If in this case, which version should I provide?
- React.js problem

  - If in this case, should I remove react or use react 16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preload.ts`, import module from electron, and declare it on window.

For example:

`preload.ts`

```js
// noinspection ES6UnusedImports
import { ipcRenderer, remote } from 'electron'; // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer;
window.remote = remote;
/* eslint-enable */
```

`index.d.ts`:

```js
interface Window {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  ipcRenderer: any;
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  remote: any;
}
```

Use:

```js
window.remote.dialog.showSaveDialogSync({});
window.ipcRenderer.send('close');
```